# Why am I not being able to write into objects I fetched from database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**What I am trying to do**: I am fetching data from MongoDB(doc). I has property files which is an array of objects. Schema of the mentioned object:

```
{
    fileName : {type : String, required : true},
    fileSize : {type : Number, required : true},
    fileOriginalName : String,
    sentEarlier : Boolean,
  }
```

and before sending this array(in doc.files) to my frontend, I want to append a property(downloadLink), to each object. The whole code where I encountered the problem:

```
Router.post('/fetch-more-files', (req, res) => {
  let {uuid} = req.body;
  File.findOne({uuid}, (err, doc) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.send({'error' : 'Something went wrong. Refresh the page.'});
    }

    if(!doc) {
      return res.send({'error' : 'Invalid link or link expired'});
    }

    let newFiles = [];

    doc.files.forEach(file => {
      file.downloadLink = `${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/files/download/${uuid}/${file.fileName}`;
    });

    doc.files.forEach(file => {
      if(!file.sentEarlier) newFiles.push(file);
    });

    doc.save((err, savedDoc) => {
      res.json({newFiles});
    });
  });
});
```

**PROBLEM**: The newFiles array which I am populating with all the files(objects inside doc.files array), those that do not have a 'sentEarlier' key true to them, when sent as response, not a single object that array has the 'downloadLink' property to them. I tried so hard and for so long to debug, but failed. Hope to find some insights as to what I could be doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what debugging have you done? why do you need 2 `doc.files.forEach(file => {`'s

Comment: oh that. I had them in the same forEach earlier. But then I tried to give it a shot, but to no vain.

Comment: Pardon my MongoDB ignorance here, but what is that `doc.save` call at the end? I thought you updated a document by calling `updateOne` on the collection. I can't find it in the MongoDB JavaScript API documentation, but I find the MongoDB documentation really hard to navigate. If you could point me at it, that would be really handy -- thanks!

Comment: I tried logging the newFile to my console(does it count as debugging) after filtering the objects and pushing them to the newFile. But the objects inside donot have the download link.

Comment: I am far more ignorant, clearly. But yea I didn't want to add a new field into my doc in DB(I can't really, because I don't have that in my schema). I just wanted to add downloadLink and render it in my view. That save is to save something else, which wasn;t much relevant to this

Comment: @DipeshTimilsina you can try [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with uodate with aggregation pipeline

Comment: @turivishal I'll look into it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: After hours of lingering and loitering over this problem, I found a solution. If you want the technical answer to why it didn't work, this is not the place for you. But if you just want your problem solved, so you can finally go pee, read on.

The answer is to use toObject() method which apparently converts the mongoose document to a plain JS object, which is now at your disposal.

toObject() in mongooseJS documentation:

[Mongoose v5.11.9:API docs | document.prototype.toObject()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Other answers are most welcome.

Comment: And thanks to that documentation link, I found the answer to my [`save`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. if you want to modify your query response just try to call your mongoose query in a different way.

```
File.findOne({uuid}, {new: true}).lean().exec((err, doc) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.send({'error' : 'Something went wrong. Refresh the page.'});
    }
    // your logic
});
```

[here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) you get more idea about lean()